# Conditional distribution $e|x$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

What is the conditional distribution of $e$ given $x$? if $e = xε$ where $x$ and $ε$ are independent $N(0, 1)$

In the book the answer is $N(0,x^2)$. But that would suppose that x is a constant and not a random variable with distribution $N (0,1)$.

Comment: The intuition behind this is that if you condition on $x$, then you "know" $x$ so that it is not random anymore, but "fixed".

Comment: Did you understand the comment above? Basically, if I set $x = x'$, then $e = x\epsilon$ would be $N(0,x'^2)$ by scaling. That is what the conditional distribution means : if I knew $x$, what would the distribution of $e$ be?